# remove duplicate rows then aggregate into one row by group using datatable

Tags: r, data.table, unique, aggregate

I have duplicate rows in a data.table - see below. A couple of the variables are lists.

```
ID  l29 s14 s2  s7  s71 s91
12345   NULL    3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
12345   NULL    NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL
12345   NULL    NULL    NULL    2   NULL    NULL
12345   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    c(4.5, 8, 9, 10)    NULL
12345   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    c(4.5, 8, 9, 10)    NULL
12345   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    c(4.5, 8, 9, 10)    NULL
12345   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    c(6, 7)
12345   11  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
12345   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    c(4.5, 8, 9, 10)    NULL
12345   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    c(6, 7)
```

I would like to summarize the above into one row as below:

```
12345   11  3   1   2   c(4.5, 8, 9, 10)    c(6, 7)
```

Someone asked me to dput the data, I hope this does it?

```
structure(list(SSN_TAX_ID = c("12345", "12345", "12345", "12345", 
"12345", "12345", "12345", "12345", "12345", "12345"), L29 = list(
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 11, NULL, NULL), 
    S14 = list(3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL), S2 = list(NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL), S7 = list(NULL, NULL, 2, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), S71 = list(NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, c(4.5, 8, 9, 10), c(4.5, 8, 9, 10), c(4.5, 8, 9, 
        10), NULL, NULL, c(4.5, 8, 9, 10), NULL), S91 = list(
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c(6, 7), NULL, NULL, 
        c(6, 7))), .Names = c("SSN_TAX_ID", "L29", "S14", "S2", 
"S7", "S71", "S91"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Could you dput an example so it's reproducible? `unique` on lists is kind of a mess in R, but `DT[,lapply(.SD, unique)]` might do it.

Comment: @Frank it combined the duplicate rows, but I also wanted the non duplicated information on one row. Using your method the 1st row is its own row since it isn't a duplicate and the duplicated rows are its own row. How do I also include the rows that aren't duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty messy, but:

```
setDT(DT) # since the OP posted a data frame
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unique(Filter(Negate(is.null), x)))]
#    SSN_TAX_ID L29 S14 S2 S7                 S71 S91
# 1:      12345  11   3  1  2  4.5, 8.0, 9.0,10.0 6,7
```

`Filter(Negate(is.null), x)` drops the NULLs from each column before we uniquify.

---

In the special case of the OP's example, using `Reduce` with `union` also happens to work:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) .(Reduce(union, x)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply function to pick unique record from each column and then remove NULL values from that.

`df<-apply(df,2,unique)
df<-unlist(df)
df<-df[df!="NULL"]`

Comment: The correct test is probably `is.null` not comparing to the string "NULL"

Comment: @Frank `is.null` and `!="NULL"` are giving same answers in this case.I am not sure but this might be an another way of doing. flexibility of R.

Comment: Yeah, I expect it to get the same answer. I guess I mean it's the canonical way to test, like you would use `is.na(x)` not `paste(x) == "NA"` to test for missing values, even if the latter works in a lot of cases.